# android BLE，write operation,in the function(Setcharacteristicnotification)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

If I carry out write operations,it means send data from phone to BLE.
ClientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE) can't run,and the app will stop.
When I writes,should it call setCharacteristicnotification?
Besides,when I write,oncharacteristicwrite staus= 133.I don't understand write very good.This is my code.

```
private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
    new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                    int childPosition, long id) {
            if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                        mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                 final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();

                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                    if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                    }
                    mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);

                }
                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
                         // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                         // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                         if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                             mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                     mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                             mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                         }
                         mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                }
                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                    mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                    System.out.println("kkkkkkkkkk+="+characteristic.getUuid());
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                            characteristic, true);
                }

                tv_uuid.setText(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                b.putString("CONNET_SATE", status);
                b.putString("UUID", characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                intent.putExtras(b);
                intent.setClass(MyGattDetail.this, FunctionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    BluetoothGattDescriptor clientConfig = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

    if (enabled) {
      clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    } else {
      clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(clientConfig);
}

public static void write(String s){
    final int charaProp = target_chara.getProperties();             
    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
        //注意: 以下读取的值 通过 BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead() 函数返回
        target_chara.setValue(s);
        mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(target_chara);
    }
}



public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}

 public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.i(TAG, "--onCharacteristicRead called--");
        byte[] sucString=characteristic.getValue();
        String string= new String(sucString);
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
    if (mOnDataAvailableListener!=null)
        mOnDataAvailableListener.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++");
    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
     Log.w(TAG, "--onCharacteristicWrite--: " + status);

     //以下语句实现 发送完数据或也显示到界面上
     broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
}
```

Comment: Kindly Edit your Question...

Answer (score 0):

133 = 0x5;

BluetoothGatt.java

```
/** Insufficient authentication for a given operation */
public static final int GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION = 0x5;
```

So 133 means Insufficient authentication for a given operation.

ClientConfig  can be null.

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor clientConfig = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
if(clientConfig !=null){

    if (enabled) {
        clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    } else {
        clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(clientConfig);
}
```